# What's wrong with this algorithm to determine Kepler parameters from orbital vectors?

Tags: orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics

I am writing computer code which instantiates a Kepler orbit given cartesian position and velocity vectors. I am working from [this reference document](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjl0cnF4K3ZAhWMesAKHY4fCQ4QFggrMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloads.rene-schwarz.com%2Fdownload%2FM002-Cartesian_State_Vectors_to_Keplerian_Orbit_Elements.pdf&usg=AOvVaw15jXuFsodbWziOPWfA5U5i).

It says:

> Calculate orbital momentum vector
>
> $\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{\dot r}$
>
> Determine the vector $\mathbf n$ pointing towards the ascending node
>
> $\mathbf n = (0,0,1)^T \times \mathbf{h} = (-h_y, h_x, 0)^T$
>
> Obtain the longitude of the ascending node
>
> $\Omega = \mathrm{arccos}(\frac{n_x}{||\mathbf{n}||})$

Suppose we have $\mathbf{r} = (X,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{\dot{r}}=(0,Y,0)$, we will end up with $\mathbf{h}=(0,0,Z)$, but this causes $\mathbf n$ to collapse to zero, and then $\Omega$ and other parameters can't be calculated.

Is the document wrong, or am I reading it wrong, or do I just need to detect and handle certain special cases? If so, what are these special cases, exhaustively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with that algorithm; everything is wrong with the longitude of the ascending node.  It is undefined when the reference plane and the orbital plane are the same.  See [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_ascending_node#Calculation_from_state_vectors) for details.  Even when they are close, and the algorithm gives you finite answers, you should expect bad numerical accuracy.  While these sorts of singular parameters are reasonable for *observational* astronomy because the corresponding observations are also singular, for *computational* astronomy you might prefer a non-singular representation.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as Mike said, it is undefined in the case of non-inclined orbits. Other way of looking at it is that all the directions in the plane of reference / orbital plane are of equal importance and therefore you can choose any of them.
In case you are struggling with the implementation [here's](http://astro.pas.rochester.edu/~aquillen/ast570/code/) something which you may find useful. The code works for all conic intersections.